# How to alert selectize attr?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I'm using selectize plugin and trying to alert custom data-attribute.

I tried with several method but it alway indefined result
My select list :

```
<select name="location_work{{counter}}" id="location_work{{counter}}" class="list_type_op" data-md-selectize-inline required>
    <option data-data='{"param": 0}'  value="1">Construction</option>
    <option data-data='{"param": 1,"name":"x"}' value="2">Puchase</option>
    <option data-data='{"param": 2,"name":"x-y"}' value="3">Warranty</option>
</select>
```

And my js function

```
    $(document).on('change', '.list_type_op', function () { 
        var selected_option = this.value;
        var nbParam =  $('option:selected', this).attr('data-param');
        alert(nbParam); //is indefined
    });
```

Select list is in Estimated price section on Type Column

Here my jsfiddle : [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/runqmyf6/18/)

Comment: Please always include the relevant code in the question. jsFiddle is having performance and connection issues right now, so your question is unanswerable.

Comment: thx for advice, i completed it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i get value of attribute with this :

```
$(document).on('change', '.list_type_op', function () { 
    var selected_option = this.value;
    var nbParam =  $(".selectize-dropdown-content").find(`[data-value='${selected_option}']`).attr('data-param');
    alert(nbParam);
});
```

I search attribute in html code.